# Data from view to controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the data of a hidden textbox from the index to a textfield in another view.

First, I get the data using AJAX.

```
//ajax
             if (id && toolcode && shopdoccode) {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'GET',
                     url: '@Url.Action("delivery", "service")',
            data: { id, memo },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    console.log("Succes");
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("delivery", "service")';
                }

            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
             }
             window.location.href = ("service/delivery?id=" + id + "&toolcode=" + toolcode + "&regdate=" + regdate + "&shopdoccode=" + shopdoccode + "&memo" + memo);
}
```

Then, I make a viewbag in the controller to pass the data to my other view.

```
public ActionResult Delivery(string id, string memo)
        {
            ServiceOrder service = GetService(id);

            ViewBag.id = id;
            ViewBag.memo = memo;
```

And finally, in the view

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("GeneratePDF", "Service", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-style-4", id = "getPDFForm" }))
    {
        string memofield = ViewBag.memo;
        //code
       <textarea name="jobdescription" readonly>@memofield</textarea>
```

if I set breakpoints in the controller, I can see that Viewbag.memo contains the correct data. Once in the view I've set a breakpoint on the string `memofield = viewbag.memo` 
Even there, I can see the data. but then, suddenly, if I press continue, the strings are back to 'null'

What am I missing here?

Comment: after pressing continue when are you inspecting those fields again?

Comment: MiaSan "$memo" + memo you are using $ instead of & window.location.href = ("service/delivery?id=" + id + "&toolcode=" + toolcode + "&regdate=" + regdate + "&shopdoccode=" + shopdoccode + "$memo" + memo);

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because after you send ajax request you are redirecting back to Delivery action window.location which does not contain post parameters id and memo.. see

```
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
          console.log("Succes");
          window.location.href = '@Url.Action("delivery", "service")';
      }
   }
```

Comment: I already tried to put it in the url but that didnt change anything